# Linear transform of bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

> Suppose that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ follow a bivariate normal distribution with parameters $\mu(Y_1)= \mu(Y_2)= 0, {\sigma^2}(Y_1)= 1, {\sigma^2}(Y_2)= 2$, and $\rho = 1/\sqrt 2$. Find a linear transformation $X_1 = a_{11} Y_1 + a_{12} Y_2, X_2 = a_{21} Y_1 + a_{22} Y_2$ such that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent standard normal random variables.

**My work so far:**

$$
f(y_1,y_2)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_{Y_1}\sigma_{y_2}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}exp{\left [ -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left(  \frac{(y_1-\mu_{Y_1})^2}{\sigma_{y_1}^2}-\frac{2\rho(y_1-\mu_{Y_1})(y_2-\mu_{Y_2})}{\sigma_{Y_1}\sigma_{Y_2}}+ \frac{(y_2-\mu_{Y_2})^2}{\sigma_{y_2}^2}\right)\right]}
$$
IF $(Y_1,Y_2)\sim N(\mu_{Y_1},\mu_{Y_2},\sigma_{Y_1}^2,\sigma_{Y_2}^2,\rho)$ then $aY_1+bY_2 \sim N(a\mu_{Y_1}+b\mu_{Y_2},a^2\sigma_{Y_1}^2+b^2\sigma_{Y_2}^2+2ab\rho\sigma_{Y_1}\sigma_{Y_2})$

$$
J(y_1,y_2)=\begin{Vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y_1} & \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y_2}  \\
\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial y_1} & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial y_2} 
\end{Vmatrix} =\begin{Vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{Vmatrix}=a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_1&=\frac{a_{12}x_2-a_{22}x_1}{a_{12}a_{21}-a_{22}a_{11}}\\
y_2&=\frac{a_{11}x_2-a_{21}x_1}{a_{22}a_{11}-a_{21}a_{12}}\\
f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2)&=J^{-1}(y_1,y_2)\cdot f_{Y_1Y_2}(\frac{a_{12}x_2-a_{22}x_1}{a_{12}a_{21}-a_{22}a_{11}},\frac{a_{11}x_2-a_{21}x_1}{a_{22}a_{11}-a_{21}a_{12}})\\
&=\frac{1}{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi}exp{\left [-\left(  \frac{(y_1)^2}{1}-\frac{2\frac{1}{\sqrt2} y_1 y_2}{1\sqrt2}+ \frac{(y_2)^2}{2}\right)\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi}exp{\left [-\left(  (\frac{a_{12}x_2-a_{22}x_1}{a_{12}a_{21}-a_{22}a_{11}})^2- (\frac{a_{12}x_2-a_{22}x_1}{a_{12}a_{21}-a_{22}a_{11}})(\frac{a_{11}x_2-a_{21}x_1}{a_{22}a_{11}-a_{21}a_{12}})+ \frac{(\frac{a_{11}x_2-a_{21}x_1}{a_{22}a_{11}-a_{21}a_{12}})^2}{2}\right)\right]}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_{X_1}&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{a_{11}^2\sigma_{Y_1}^2+a_{12}^2\sigma_{Y_2}^2+2a_{11}a_{12}\rho\sigma_{Y_1}\sigma_{Y_2}}}exp\left[ -\frac{x_1-(a_{11}\mu_{Y_1}+a_{12}\mu_{Y_2})}{2(a_{11}^2\sigma_{Y_1}^2+a_{12}^2\sigma_{Y_2}^2+2a_{11}a_{12}\rho\sigma_{Y_1}\sigma_{Y_2})}\right]\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{a_{11}^2+2a_{12}^2+2a_{11}a_{12}}}exp\left[ -\frac{x_1}{2(a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2\cdot2+2a_{11}a_{12})}\right]\\
f_{X_2}&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{a_{21}^2\sigma_{Y_1}^2+a_{22}^2\sigma_{Y_2}^2+2a_{21}a_{22}\rho\sigma_{Y_1}\sigma_{Y_2}}}exp\left[ -\frac{x_2-(a_{21}\mu_{Y_1}+a_{22}\mu_{Y_2})}{2(a_{21}^2\sigma_{Y_1}^2+a_{22}^2\sigma_{Y_2}^2+2a_{21}a_{22}\rho\sigma_{Y_1}\sigma_{Y_2})}\right]\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{a_{21}^2+2a_{22}^2+2a_{21}a_{22}}}exp\left[ -\frac{x_2}{2(a_{21}^2+a_{22}^2\cdot2+2a_{21}a_{22})}\right]\\
f_{X1}f_{X_2}&=\frac1{2\pi\sqrt{a_{11}^2+2a_{12}^2+2a_{11}a_{12}}\sqrt{a_{21}^2+2a_{22}^2+2a_{21}a_{22}}}exp\left[ -\frac{x_1}{2(a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2\cdot2+2a_{11}a_{12})}-\frac{x_2}{2(a_{21}^2+a_{22}^2\cdot2+2a_{21}a_{22})}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
$$f_{X_1X_2}(x_1,x_2)=f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)
$$
---Thank you StubbornAtom,I overlooked the key word "standard "

$$
\begin{aligned}
a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}=1\\ a_{11}^2+2a_{12}^2+2a_{11}a_{12}=1\\a_{21}^2+2a_{22}^2+2a_{21}a_{22}=1\\
2a_{12}a_{22}+a_{12}a_{21}+a_{11}a_{22}+a_{11}a_{21}=0
\end{aligned}
$$

$$a_{11}=1 ,a_{12}=0 ,a_{21}=-1 a_{22}=1$$ In my opinion,There is no sinlger answer for my question.

Comment: Since $(X_1,X_2)$ is jointly normal, they are independent iff they are uncorrelated. Find the constants from this condition and from the means and variances of $X_1,X_2$.

Comment: The answer in the book: $x_1=y_1,x_2=-y_1+y_2 $ in other words $a_{11}=1,a_{12}=0,a_{21}=-1,a_{22}=1$

Answer (score 1):

The covariance matrix of $A \mathbf Y$ is $A \Sigma A^t = I$, therefore we need to solve the equation $A^t A = \Sigma^{-1}$. We can look for an upper-triangular $A$ (the Cholesky decomposition), which gives
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ 0 & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}^t
\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ 0 & a_{22} \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}^2 & a_{11} a_{12} \\ a_{11} a_{12} & a_{12}^2 + a_{22}^2
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
from which we find $a_{11}$, then $a_{12}$, then $a_{22}$.

Answer (score 0):

A standard way of solving that is by using the $U\Sigma U^\dagger$ decomposition. The [Jordan decomposition of your covariance matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordan%20decomp%20%7B%7B1,1%7D,%7B1,2%7D%7D) (with unitary matrices) is given by
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
1&2
\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-1-\sqrt 5}{\sqrt{6}}&\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{\sqrt{6}}\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}&0\\
0&\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-1-\sqrt 5}{\sqrt{6}}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{\sqrt{6}}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Hence if
\begin{align*}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-1-\sqrt 5}{\sqrt{6}}&\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{\sqrt{6}}\\
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\end{align*}

Then $\begin{bmatrix}
X_1\\X_2
\end{bmatrix}=A \begin{bmatrix}
X_1\\X_2
\end{bmatrix}\sim \mathcal N\left( \begin{bmatrix}
0\\0
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}&0\\
0&\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}
\end{bmatrix} \right)$

Comment: $X_1,X_2$ are supposed to be standard normal.